# Javascript run multiple jobs synchronously (vuejs, axios)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want get data with APIs, merge data and do some with for-loops.

After that, show results to the screen.

**But in my case, I can't use v-if in template because of some UI scenario.**

How can do all of this synchronously?

API.js

```
getDataNum1: () => {
    return axios.get("/api/data1");
},
getDataNum2: () => {
    return axios.get("/api/data2");
}
```

Test.vue

```
 <div v-model="mergeDataList"></div>
 
 <script>
     methods: {
          initialize() {
               let mergedList = this._mergeData();
               let convertedList = [];
               _.forEach(mergedList, function(item){
                     convertedList.push(item.name + item.value);  // need some works not-simple 
               });
               this.mergeDataList = convertedList;
          },
          _mergeData() {
               let that = this;
               API.getDataNum1().then((response)=>{that.data1 = response.data;});
               API.getDataNum2().then((response)=>{that.data2 = response.data;});
               return data1.concat(data2);
          }
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: since axios calls return promises, your promise `.then` method ... alternatively use async/await - though ... nothing will make it synchronous, since you can't turn asynchronous into synchronous code without breaking the laws of time and space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [async-await](https://javascript.info/async-await) for this to make it easier,

```
async _mergeData() {
  let that = this;
  let { data: data1 } = await API.getDataNum1();
  let { data: data2 } = await API.getDataNum2()
  return data1.concat(data2);
}
```

if you specifically want to use `promises`, you can [chain](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) them and get the same behaviour,

```
let data = []
API.getDataNum1().then(response => {
  data = data.concat(response.data);
  return API.getDataNum2();
}).then(response => {
  data = data.concat(response.data);
})
```

Or you can use the [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) way of doing things but this rejects as a whole if any of the promises rejects,

```
Promise.all([API.getDataNum1(), API.getDataNum2()]).then(values => {
  let data = [...values]
})
```

You can also look at the newer [`Promise.allSettled`](https://javascript.info/promise-api#promise-allsettled) API for easier error handling,

```
Promise.allSettled([API.getDataNum1(), API.getDataNum1()]).then(results => {
  for (let result in results) {
    if (result.status === 'fulfilled') {
      data = data.concat(results.value)
    } else {
      console.log(`Failure reason: ${result.reason}`);
    }

  }
})
```

Both `Promise.all` and `Promise.allSettled` aren't supported in IE but if you're using babel, you should be covered there.